# Getting from committed to beta

Tags: discussion

I am really interested in seeing a particular site become 'beta', but it is stuck in 'committed'. From all I've read (the FAQ's other related questions), it is still not clear to me what I can do.

The way I found the site to commit to was through a vote to close in another group that said 'This question isn't appropriate for this group' and I thought to myself 'I wonder if there's an Area 51 site being worked on'.

How can we (people already committed) put that idea more directly into people's heads? I fell like 'commit' is a single passive vote, and then that's all you can do.

So what do you suggest to help actively move things from commit stage to beta?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: Share This]

Comment: Great!...except I don't have that link -and- it has a button instead of 'Uncommit' that says 'Commit'. But other labels say that I -am- committed. So am I or not?

Comment: Argh...I am...just had to make sure I was logged in (somehow logging in one doesn't always log in to others you link to directly).

Comment: OK. that link is an excellent way to spread around a URL to others, -if- you do twitter, facebook, delicious, blog, homepage, etc. But I feel like advertising will be very well responded to right here on obvious sister sites. When superuser and serverfault came out -and- they were advertised as coming out, I joined immediately. Shouldn't it be kosher (somehow I feel it is not) for -someone- (let's say a moedrator) to post a non-meta announcement of a possible sister site?

Comment: @Mitch: A non-meta announcement is pretty much by definition going to be off-topic (unless you're referring to the system message type of announcement, which is not intended to be used often). You might be able to post an announcement on a meta site and get a moderator to tag it as `[featured]`, which would make it appear in ads on the parent site.